# Begin Transaction within Begin Transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

Good day everyone.
I have a doubt that probably some of you may solve.
I wrote a stored-procedure which, inside a `TRANSACTION`, at a certain point calls another stored-procedure which has itself a `TRANSACTION`.
Both have a TRY-CATCH structure which will rollback in case of error.

If the nested stored-procedure fails, and "rollsback", will the parent catch the error automatically and rollback itself, or I do have to check the return message and in case throw an error?

Following is the call to the nested stored-procedure which result, in case of success, will be "OK".

```
EXEC [sp_DELETE_WC_RG_RE_ASSET]
@idWcRgReAsset = @idWcRgReAsset,
@msg = @ret output;
```

Comment: Nested transactions, in SQL Server, are a Myth: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

Comment: And debugging that is going to be challenging too because your inner procedure is swallowing the exception which means you wont get the exception to know what went wrong. Unless you catch it and rethrow it, in which case I would suggest just letting it bubble up.

Comment: @SeanLange So you're suggesting to do this: `IF (@ret != 'OK') THROW 51000, @ret, 1;`

Comment: Actually I would suggest not handling errors at all in the inner procedure. Let them happen, then your calling procedure can handle them. Far too often I see people trying to prevent errors. You can't prevent them, they are a natural occurrence of software. They need to be handled instead of being prevented.

Comment: Once a rollback occurs the entire stack of transactions are rolled back. You can test anywhere (usually done in a catch block) if you are in a transaction by issuing a if @@transcount>0 then print 'I am in a transaction'

Comment: I suggest you read Erland's discussion of error handling [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). Short answer - yes, you have to check.